# Автоматически добавлять вывод var_dump и подобных в декодируемом виде

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Довольно часто постят вопросы, где кидают простыню вывода на пару экранов, а отвечающий должен хотя бы минимально переписать структуру в рабочий ввод для создания ответа на этой основе.
Пример вопроса [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/845912/207618).

Вопрос **до** внедрения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос **после** внедрения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть подобные ресурсы типа [этого](https://www.nestforms.com/php-print_r-to-json-online) (вывод `print_r` преобразуется в `json`, который декодируется в примере сам через `json_decode`), но это только для одной функции и сторонний инструмент, который надо найти.

Предложение просто: определять наличие подобного вывода и добавлять преобразованную строку ниже с, возможно, пометкой для чего это добавлено.

Уверен, подобное можно сделать не только для PHP, если требуется.

Comment: Чтобы что-то стали прикручивать для автоматики, это должно стать более массовым явлением, имхо.

Comment: @alexolut, Я иногда вижу, поэтому почему бы не предложить? Хуже не станет.

Comment: для меня это как-то малопонятно выглядит. Можно как-то поподробнее расписать идею?

Comment: @alexolut, Спросите точнее, я не вижу что тут непонятного, поэтому не знаю что расписывать.

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть вопрос **до и после** упомянутых в предложении модификаций.

Comment: Без примера действительно непонятно. Уточните плиз, "определять простыню кода" и добавлять к ней что, где и как?

Comment: @alexolut, Так?

Comment: @Other так понятнее, но идея, имхо, слишком специфична.

Comment: @alexolut, Целое состоит из частных.